# Make a negative number positive

Tags: java, negative-number

I have a Java method in which I'm summing a set of numbers. However, I want any negatives numbers to be treated as positives. So (1)+(2)+(1)+(-1) should equal 5.

I'm sure there is very easy way of doing this - I just don't know how.

Comment: simple maths http://stackoverflow.com/a/5220597/185022 :)

Comment: Amazes me how such basic questions do get so many upvotes...

Comment: My questions are more reasonable than this but yet it has so more downvotes

Comment: Multiply the number itself by -1

Answer (score 455, accepted):

Just call [Math.abs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-). For example:

```
int x = Math.abs(-5);
```

Which will set `x` to `5`.

Note that if you pass `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the same value (still negative) will be returned, as the range of `int` does not allow the positive equivalent to be represented.

Comment: Note the edge cases, e.g. Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) = Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: ((a <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - a : a)

Comment: This does not cover the edge condition for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Refer this https://youtu.be/IWrpDP-ad7g

Comment: @vs_lala: Yup, have added a note.

Comment: use Math.absExact from JDK15 on. If the argument is Integer.MIN_VALUE you'll get an ArithmeticException

Answer (score 109):

The concept you are describing is called "absolute value", and Java has a function called [Math.abs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(int)) to do it for you.  Or you could avoid the function call and do it yourself:

```
number = (number < 0 ? -number : number);
```

or

```
if (number < 0)
    number = -number;
```

Comment: Oh, dilemma time - there are so many equally good answers, that I might as well delete mine.  But then I'd lose 40 points, and I'll never catch Jon Skeet if I do that.

Comment: Sorry -1 for reinventing a standard library call.

Comment: @cletus, did you notice that I had already mentioned the standard library call?  Or that in this case, the "reinvent" takes fewer instructions that calling the library?

Comment: Also worth understanding the details behind the library call.  Especially if there are side effects to the library call, or performance issues like Paul mentions.

Comment: This doesn't work for "-2147483648", guess why ?

Answer (score 21):

You're looking for absolute value, mate. `Math.abs(-5)` returns 5...

Answer (score 12):

Use the `abs` function:

```
int sum=0;
for(Integer i : container)
  sum+=Math.abs(i);
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this (the negative in front of the x is valid since it is a unary operator, find more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)):

```
int answer = -x;
```

With this, you can turn a positive to a negative and a negative to a positive.

---

**However**, if you want to only make a negative number positive then try this:

```
int answer = Math.abs(x);
```

---

**A little cool math trick!** Squaring the number will guarantee a positive value of x^2, and then, taking the square root will get you to the absolute value of x:

```
int answer = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2));
```

Hope it helps! Good Luck!

Comment: long instead of int would be beneficial for large numbers.

Answer (score 7):

> This code is **not** safe to be called on positive numbers.

```
int x = -20
int y = x + (2*(-1*x));
// Therefore y = -20 + (40) = 20
```

Comment: We can multiply with -1 instead of doing this. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 6):

Are you asking about absolute values?

Math.abs(...) is the function you probably want.

Answer (score 6):

You want to wrap each number into `Math.abs()`. e.g.

```
System.out.println(Math.abs(-1));
```

prints out "1".

If you want to avoid writing the `Math.`-part, you can include the Math util statically. Just write

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
```

along with your imports, and you can refer to the `abs()`-function just by writing

```
System.out.println(abs(-1));
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest, if verbose way to do this is to wrap each number in a Math.abs() call, so you would add:

```
Math.abs(1) + Math.abs(2) + Math.abs(1) + Math.abs(-1)
```

with logic changes to reflect how your code is structured.  Verbose, perhaps, but it does what you want.

Comment: You could make it less verbose with a static import.

Comment: If he has direct control over the values, wouldn't it be better to simply remove the `-` sign(s)? Or otherwise, including if he doesn't have control, wouldn't it be better to use a function like `absoluteSum( int[] values ){ /*loop with Math.abs()*/ }` instead of manually wrapping Math.abs() in each value? [-1]

Comment: I agree.  Encapsulating the logic in a well-named function will make this more clear.

Answer (score 5):

When you need to represent a value without the concept of a loss or absence (negative value), that is called "absolute value".

---

The logic to obtain the absolute value is very simple: `"If it's positive, maintain it. If it's negative, negate it"`.

---

What this means is that your logic and code should work like the following:

```
//If value is negative...
if ( value < 0 ) {
  //...negate it (make it a negative negative-value, thus a positive value).
  value = negate(value);
}
```

---

There are 2 ways you can negate a value:

1. By, well, negating it's value: `value = (-value);`
2. By multiplying it by "100% negative", or "-1": `value = value *
   (-1);`

Both are actually two sides of the same coin. It's just that you usually don't remember that `value = (-value);` is actually `value = 1 * (-value);`.

---

Well, as for how you actually do it in Java, it's very simple, because Java already provides a function for that, in the `Math class`: `value = Math.abs(value);`

Yes, doing it without `Math.abs()` is just a line of code with very simple math, but why make your code look ugly? Just use Java's provided `Math.abs()` function! They provide it for a reason!

If you absolutely need to skip the function, you can use `value = (value < 0) ? (-value) : value;`, which is simply a more compact version of the code I mentioned in the logic (3rd) section, using the [Ternary operator (`? :`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

---

Additionally, there might be situations where you want to always represent loss or absence within a function that might receive both positive and negative values.

Instead of doing some complicated check, you can simply get the absolute value, and negate it: `negativeValue = (-Math.abs(value));`

---

With that in mind, and considering a case with a sum of multiple numbers such as yours, it would be a nice idea to implement a function:

```
int getSumOfAllAbsolutes(int[] values){
  int total = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<values.lenght; i++){
    total += Math.abs(values[i]);
  }
  return total;
}
```

---

Depending on the probability you might need related code again, it might also be a good idea to add them to your own "utils" library, splitting such functions into their core components first, and  maintaining the final function simply as a nest of calls to the core components' now-split functions:

```
int[] makeAllAbsolute(int[] values){
  //@TIP: You can also make a reference-based version of this function, so that allocating 'absolutes[]' is not needed, thus optimizing.
  int[] absolutes = values.clone();
  for(int i=0; i<values.lenght; i++){
    absolutes[i] = Math.abs(values[i]);
  }
  return absolutes;
}

int getSumOfAllValues(int[] values){
  int total = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<values.lenght; i++){
    total += values[i];
  }
return total;
}

int getSumOfAllAbsolutes(int[] values){
  return getSumOfAllValues(makeAllAbsolute(values));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you **`multiply that number with -1`**?

Like This:

```
//Given x as the number, if x is less than 0, return 0 - x, otherwise return x:
return (x <= 0.0F) ? 0.0F - x : x;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in the mechanics of two's complement, here's the absolutely inefficient, but illustrative low-level way this is made:

```
private static int makeAbsolute(int number){
     if(number >=0){
        return number;
     } else{
        return (~number)+1;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why is it absolutely inefficient? I don't see any looping that makes it inefficient. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Library function `Math.abs()` can be used.
`Math.abs()` returns the absolute value of the argument

> - if the argument is negative, it returns the negation of the argument.
> - if the argument is positive, it returns the number as it is.

e.g:

1. `int x=-5;`
   `System.out.println(Math.abs(x));`

Output: 5

2. `int y=6;`
   `System.out.println(Math.abs(y));`

Output: 6

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "-1139627840";
BigInteger bg1 = new BigInteger(s);
System.out.println(bg1.abs());
```

Alternatively:

```
int i = -123;
System.out.println(Math.abs(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following solutions:

**without lib fun:**

```
    value = (value*value)/value
```

*(The above does not actually work.)*

**with lib fun:**

```
   value = Math.abs(value);
```

Comment: wouldn't the first one result in a negative number again?

Answer (score 1):

To convert negative number to positive number (this is called absolute value), uses Math.abs(). This Math.abs() method is work like this

`“number = (number < 0 ? -number : number);".`

**In below example, `Math.abs(-1)` will convert the negative number 1 to positive 1.**

> example

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int total = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + (-1);
    
    //output 3
    System.out.println("Total : " + total);
    
    int total2 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + Math.abs(-1);
    
    //output 5
    System.out.println("Total 2 (absolute value) : " + total2);
    
}
```

> ***Output***
>
> Total : 3
> Total 2 (absolute value) : 5

Answer (score 1):

I see people are saying that `Math.abs(number)` but this method is not full proof.

This fails when you try to wrap `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` (see ref. https://youtu.be/IWrpDP-ad7g)

If you are not sure whether you are going to receive the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in the input. It is always recommended to check for that number and handle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the absolute value of a long , and looked deeply into Math.abs and found that if my argument is less than LONG.MIN_VAL which is -9223372036854775808l, then the abs function would not return an absolute value but only the minimum value. Inthis case if your code is using this abs value further then there might be an issue.

Comment: The whole point of Long.MIN_VAL is that you can't have a long that's "less than LONG.MIN_VAL".

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one?

```
public static int toPositive(int number) {
    return number & 0x7fffffff;
}
```

Comment: On a ten year old question with 17 other answers you should be explaining what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Starting an answer with a question is a good way to get it closed if it ends up in the review queues.

Comment: this is not correct. -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF, then -0xFFFFFFFF & 0x7FFFFFFF = 0x7FFFFFFFFF which is different from 1. As expected the integer binary format for negative number is complement to 2, so this can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(arr[i]<0)

Math.abs(arr[i]);  //1st way (taking absolute value)

arr[i]=-(arr[i]); //2nd way (taking -ve of -ve no. yields a +ve no.)

arr[i]= ~(arr[i]-1);   //3rd way (taking negation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the for loop:

```
sum += Math.abs(arr[i])
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, a person who needs to ask this type of question may also need to have little more explained about what Math.abs() function is and possibly even what += does.

Comment: I suggest that the folks to read the entire thread from the top to bottom, so that any clarifications may have been already addressed at the top. Math.abs returns the positive and absolute value of the integer number while += operation is the omitted version of sum = sum + arr[i].

Comment: This comment was about this specific answer. An Answer should not have to rely on another answer to be a complete answer especially when it does not reference the other answer. Also what happens if the other answer is removed and this question is left with this inadequate response.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_math_abs.asp is where you can find how math.abs works, and https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_operators.asp is where you will know what += does.

Comment: Then that needs to be in your answer. You shouldn't assume the questioner knows where to find that information.

Answer (score -1):

In kotlin you can use unaryPlus

```
input = input.unaryPlus()
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/unary-plus.html

Comment: it does nothing for negative numbers. How did it worked for you? there is little info in the docs you have linked

Answer (score -3):

dont do this

number = (number < 0 ? -number : number);

or

if (number < 0) number = -number;

this will be an bug when you run find bug on your code it will report it as RV_NEGATING_RESULT_OF