# how to make -2147483648 a positive number in Java?

Tags: java

My question: how to make -2147483648 a positive number in Java?

My thoughts:
There are many ways to make a negative number positive:

[Make a negative number positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493494/make-a-negative-number-positive)

however, for the edge case, where the min value of a int in Java is -2147483648, all those methods do not work.

What should I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: What value do you expect? Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: `2147483648` is out of the range of an int. What should the positive value be for `-2147483648`?

Comment: That's beyond the limitations for int. You need to use a different datatype.

Comment: if (num == -2147483648) num = 27;

Comment: @GBlodgett  I was doing a leetcode practice. https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/ .  The question asks to reverse a number.  The method is limited to receive a int datatype where the input is -2147483648. I want to get rid of the sign before I put it into StringBuilder and reverse it. And now realising I can not make it positive simply. Thanks.

Comment: @HelenCui From the problem description: `For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you care about it staying an `int`: you can't. The `int` primitive fits only values from -2147483648 up to and including 2147483647.

However, if you just want to turn -2147483648 into the integer number 2147483648, then use a `long`:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int v = -2147483648;
    long r = -(long)v;
    System.out.print(r);
  }
}
```

And done: `2147483648`.

Of course, also read through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html to get familiar with the limitations of all the primitive data types. And if that still isn't enough and you need arbitrary length integers, [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is available.

Comment: if that's still not enough (you'll have the same problem again at Long.MIN_VALUE), you can use BigInteger

Comment: The input int cannot be Long.MIN_VALUE

Comment: Keith means that if, after switching to `long` data types, you end up in a situation where you need some `n` that is either less than `Long.MIN_VALUE` or higher than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, you'll want to use a BigInteger, which has no value limitation, at the cost of also not having a fixed memory footprint or standard operator based arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

> My question: how to make -2147483648 a positive number in Java?

There is no value that is representable as an `int` that is equal to `+2147483648`.

So the idea of "making -2147483648 positive" as an `int` has no meaning.  You simply cannot do it<sup>1</sup>.

But you could represent `+2147483648` as a `long` or as a `BigInteger` (or a few other ways with various caveats.)

---

> What should I do?

Use `long` (though that has the same issue with `Long.MIN_VALUE`) or `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` or some other representation.

Or just treat this as a "feature" rather than a problem ... and work around it.  For example, remove the sign after you have put it into the `StringBuilder` or treat -2147483648 as a special case.

---

<sup>1 - It is a mathematical fact that [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed representations are not symmetric about zero.  There is one more negative number ( < 0) than positive ( > 0), and therefore one negative number doesn't have a corresponding positive number.</sup>